# The Spring Boot way to do LDAP authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have the following working codes that can authenticate a user with LDAP. As you can see, it's very simple. But how can I do the same thing the Spring Boot way?

```
     try {
            Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, “ldaps://xxxxxxxx.abcgroup.xyz.com:636”);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); // fixed value
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, “myid@abcgroup.xyz.com”);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mypassword");
            new InitialDirContext(env);
           // authentication successful.
      } catch (Exception exception) {
           // authentication failed.
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should write your Connection information in a Configuration file,for example a ldap.yml file.

```
ldap:
  url: ldap://XXXXXXX:389/
  root: cn=root,dc=root,dc=com
  userDn: cn=root,dc=root,dc=com
  password: XXXXXX
  baseDN: dc=root,dc=com
  clean: true
  pooled: false
```

And then using these attribute inject a ldaptemplate bean,this is  a propeties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ldap")
public class LdapProperties {
private String url;
private String userDn;
private String password;
private String baseDN;
private String clean;
private String root;
private boolean pooled = false;
}
```

this is a Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LdapProperties.class})
public class LdapConfiguration {
@Autowired
LdapProperties ldapProperties;
@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getUrl());
    contextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getUserDn());
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getPassword());
    contextSource.setPooled(ldapProperties.getPooled());
    contextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getBaseDN());
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
   }
   }
```

And then you can use  @Autowired Annotations.This annotation allows Spring to resolve and inject collaborating beans into your bean.

```
    @Autowired
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
```

Using ldapTemplate you could do CRUD like a relational database.of course you can do authentication things.
This is my first time answer questions in stackoverflow ,I welcome you to point out my mistakes.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! Actually I had already figured out how to solve my problem. My solution is different from yours.

Comment: Could you please share your solution if possible?I'm also a beginner in ldap,maybe we can communicate in some questions.